# Monomial replacement in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, expression

I found some examples on string replacement  in  Haskell but I didn't find one that does replacement in polynomials, for example,

`1 + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p]` should return `1+f[2]+f[4]`. Is this kind of replacement supported by Haskell ?

Comment: What are the types of your polynomials?

Comment: I can start with the most basic ones.

Comment: And what Regex library are you using? If you want to do this with regexes then this is more a property of the library than of Haskell. A better approach would be to parse the string properly into a datatype representing the polynomial expression and do the transformation on that.

Comment: I mean, what is the *Haskell* type of the polynomials, i.e. how do you want to represent them in the computer?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor : I have been trying to create some programs using Data.Polynomials. I hope I am telling what you have asked. Though I haven't successfully created any program yet(as I started yesterday on it). But I was wondering if its possible or not.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam : I read some programs theoretically on SO, so this popped to me. Do you have some mimimal example to explain, I find it somewhat logical as I read something similar recently somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean this package? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/toysolver-0.0.6/docs/Data-Polynomial.html

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam : yes, this is the one I tried. There is another with Math.Polynomial too but I still have to try hard with both.

Comment: I am excited to know why it was downvoted, I am open to suggestions, plz share it with me.

Comment: @Lawjes: I did not downvote but you should definitely include the link to the package in the question; without this information it's imprecise.

Answer (score 5):

Might I suggest not doing that? `String` is really the data type we banish things that have no structure, you have an actual AST here so parsing into something which represents is just going to be much easier.

There are plenty of [nice](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/toysolver-0.0.6/docs/Data-Polynomial.html) libraries for stuff like this. But if you wanted to do it on your own

```
data Term = Var String
          | Const Integer
          | Term :*: Term
          | Term :+: Term
          | Term :-: Term
          | Term :^: Term
          deriving(Eq, Show, Ord)
infixr 8 :^: -- Mimic (^) from prelude

instance Num Term where
  fromInteger = Const
  (*) = (:*:)
  (+) = (:+:)
  (-) = (:-:)

-- From Data.String
instance IsString Term where
  fromString = Var
```

Now you if you turn on the language extension `OverloadedStrings` you could write `"x" * 4 + 2` and get back `Plus (Mult (Var "x") (Const 4)) (Const 2)`

So now for your problem, instead of using regexs, use goodness to honest pattern matching!
For example, you're rule was to translate every occurence of `x^p` to `f p`. Now let's assume that `f` is some mathematical function and can be given the type `Term -> Term`. We'll start with a function that recursively rewrites a tree

```
 rewrite :: (Term -> Term) -> Term -> Term
 rewrite f c@(Const _) = f c
 rewrite f v@(Var _)   = f v
 rewrite f (t1 :*: t2) = f $ rewrite f t1 :*: rewrite f t2
 rewrite f (t1 :+: t2) = f $ rewrite f t1 :+: rewrite f t2
 rewrite f (t1 :-: t2) = f $ rewrite f t1 :-: rewrite f t2
 rewrite f (t1 :^: t2) = f $ rewrite f t1 :^: rewrite f t2
```

This function just rewrites a term tree bottom up. Now your could would be

```
 powToF :: Term -> Term
 powToF ("x" :^: p) = f p
 powToF a           = a

 transform = rewrite powToF
```

And thats' it. It's fairly easy to write other transformations like this as well. I'll leave it to you how to pretty print a term (it's not too bad) and parse one.

Comment: This is nice detailed answer but is it not that I will have to write a rule every time I want to replace, as there might be endless replacement terms. I hope I am not interpreting it wrong.

Comment: @LawjesJaknap Can you describe "endless replacement terms"? Do you mean you apply a rewrite rule, and a different one, and the first one, over and over and over again?

Comment: Yes one time it might be x^p_, than x^2 than x^3 etc.

Comment: @LawjesJaknap I'm afraid I don't understand what your saying, a system like this would apply `powToF` over all the terms `x^y` and turn them into `f y` everywhere in a term tree. This is exactly the same is if you had some regex that textually substituted `x^y` for `f y`

Comment: The only way for this to loop forever is if you applied infinitely many rewrite rules, which would get stuck in any sane rewriting system.

Comment: This is a feature of mathematica and its a brilliant feature that I noticed is missing in other tools. Here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html

Comment: @LawjesJaknap Well I can't rewrite all of mathematica in one page of Haskell, but this is functionally identical to my implementation, the only difference is instead of `x -> y`, you must write `f x -> y; f a a`. That's it. Also mine does rewrite subterms.

Comment: To not rewrite subterms, instead of `rewrite f term`, you'd just do `f term`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't terrifically hard to do in Haskell; the challenge has more to do with what kinds of structure you're interested in taking advantage of and what kinds of replacements you will make. Mathematica obscures a lot of the details by simply picking a certain kind of structure and replacement methodology. I'll explore a couple examples (warning, untested code).

If we're generally just interested in monomial replacement then that can be done by representing fully reduced polynomials as lists of coefficients.

```
 a + b x^2 + c x^3 + d x^4 + ...
[a , b     , c     , d     , ... ]
```

and we can trivially replace a monomial with a function like

```
type Coef  = Int
type Power = Int
type Poly  = [Coef]

replaceMonomial :: Power -> (Coef -> Poly) -> Poly -> Poly
replaceMonomial pow repl poly = zipWith (+) poly' (repl coef)
  where
    (poly', coef) = splitPoly pow poly [] 

    -- pulls a particular monomial out of a polynomial
    --
    -- >>> splitPoly 3 [1,2,3,4,5] []
    -- ([1,2,3,0,5], 4)
    splitPoly n []     acc = (reverse acc, 0)
    splitPoly 0 (x:xs) acc = (reverse acc ++ (0:xs), x)
    splitPoly n (x:xs) acc = splitPoly (n-1) xs (n:acc)
```

This method is fast and canonical but requires, obviously, that we've actually got full polynomial structure on our "string" and that we're replacing single monomials only. It could be extended easily to do multiple-monomial replacement, though.

In the other direction from canonicity we can also do full replacement of subtrees based on syntactic equality.

```
data Poly
  = X
  | Poly :*: Poly
  | Poly :+: Poly
  | Act Coef Poly
  deriving ( Eq )   -- important!

-- really inefficient!
replaceSubtree :: Poly -> Poly -> Poly -> Poly
replaceSubtree redex repl target
  | target == redex = repl
  | otherwise = case target of
    X         -> X
    p1 :*: p2 ->     replaceSubtree redex repl p1 
                 :*: replaceSubtree redex repl p2
    p1 :+: p2 ->     replaceSubtree redex repl p1 
                 :+: replaceSubtree redex repl p2
    Act c p   -> Act c $ replaceSubtree redex repl p
```

Here we treat any syntactic subtree of an expression as a potentially "reducible expression" (`redex`) and using Haskell's built-in notion of structural, syntactic equality we search for targets and try to replace them. It's super inefficient since each equality check will traverse the entire subtree that is just about to be descended into, but the idea stands.

The real deficiency of this method is that it depends upon syntactic equality instead of denotational equality---there's no notion of a monomial replacement possible since we'd have to reduce the polynomial to a standard form first. Given some function that performs that reduction it's easy enough to build `replaceStandardPolynomial` by just canonizing the input polynomial first.

Finally, there's the notion of variable replacement and capture. If we have a polynomial over multiple variables and want to replace them (intentiate them) sanely with expressions which may also contain variables then we'll need much more machinery. Fortunately, that's such a common operation in programming languages that there are simply oodles of methods. To this end, I'd highly suggest studying the [`bound`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) and [`unification-fd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unification-fd) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica and Haskell have different philosophies.

The polynomial you built in Mathematica is a white box built out of provided operators. The polynomial in Haskell's `Data.Polynomial` library is an *abstract datatype*. You can interact with abstract datatypes only by invoking their interface. In this case, you can use `coeffMap` in `Data.Polynomial` to obtain the polynomial as a `Map`, and then compute the sum of entries in the map.

Mathematica has indiscriminate pattern matching on expression tree. Haskell has abstraction, which means you cannot "peek inside" an arbitrary value in general. It forces that your operations respect the internals of its structure. Consider your operation on `1 + x + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p]`. This is `1+x+f[2]+f[4]`. It's oblivious to the meaning of the expression. It would be far more natural to get `1+f[1]+f[2]+f[4]` or `f[0]+f[1]+f[2]+f[4]` since `x` is the same thing as `x^1`. In Mathematica it is possible to write "x /. 2 -> 3" to replace "2"s in an expression by "3"s, which to me is frankly a frightening possibility.

Haskell purposefully does not have this type of pattern matching. You are forced to think about the domain of computation, and use functions that respect its structure, or tear it down with Haskell's pattern matching if you can't build your operation using provided combinators. In your case, you should either use the interface provided by `Data.Polynomial` or, as others said, build your own expression type and give it a substitution function.

The closest thing I know to deep traversal in Mathematica is the Scrap your boilerplate library. See the syb package on hackage and page 2 of http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/hmap.ps. I think it won't be useful here.

Comment: this is a good comparison, but does it suggest that its not possible to do it in Haskell ?

Comment: @Lawjes: What is not possible? (1) You can have expression trees in Haskell and match on them, see J. Abrahamson's answer. (2) You cannot perform operations on abstract datatypes which are not in their API; that's the point of abstract datatypes. (3) You can write an equivalent of `/. x^p_ -> f[p]` on polynomials in `Data.Polynomial` by using `coeffMap`.